# swing окошко не выдает мне

Tags: java, swing

```
package Working.Home;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingDemo extends JFrame {

    SwingDemo(){

        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame(" A simple Swing Application");    
        jfrm.setSize(275, 100);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel jlab = new JLabel("Swing defines the modern Java GUI");    
        jfrm.add(jlab);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Изучаю сейчас джаву, но почему-то когда подключаю swing, код работает хорошо, но вот окошко не выдает мне. Когда с апплетом, то все хорошо было. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Можно и без `demo.setVisible(true)`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Неудивительно: ваш метод `main` практически ничего не делает. Вы запускаете пустой `run`, и всё.

Попробуйте так:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    SwingDemo demo = new SwingDemo();
    demo.setVisible(true);
}
```